What its this strange file named "D" in the Windows folder?
One month ago I discovered a strange "D" file in the Windows folder. Its size is 10GB, however when I played some games, it would rise up to 13GB. It is a system file and it's used by the process with PID 4, same as the System process. I can't delete it, because it's used by other program and it's hidden as well.
It looks like it boots up alongside with the system itself and its date of change updates everyday. This file was created on September 11th and at the same day my Windows 10 received an update.
I find it strange, because I've been using this laptop for almost a year and there was no such file and then it just appeared, especially with such a large size.
I've been searching this question online but haven't found an answer even in the exact same topic on this site.
Properties:
General tab:

Details tab:

Security tab:


Files do not have process identifiers. Please be precise in wording your information.

@DanielB They do according to Resource Monitor (may also be the source of OP's info if they haven't themselves used Resource Monitor). According to that unanswered duplicate the file is actually D.sys, OP likely has extensions hidden as is default on Windows.

They don't. But OP already changed the wording: The file is opened by PID 4. The filename also definitely, in both questions, is just D.
